# send file via email andoid(couldnt attach file)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, file, email

good day! so basicly im creating a file and then sending it via email everything works but when gmail app opens there is a message "couldn`t attach file". please give me any sugestions what should i do
Thanks!
my code:

```
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("Android/data/app.myapp")+"/", FILE_NAME);


    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
       
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file, true);

        outputStream.write(textToWrite.getBytes());
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
      
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(!file.exists())
    {
        Toast.makeText(  MainActivity.this,"doesnt exist",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if( file.exists())
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Send Text File");
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"");
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("content://" + file.getAbsoluteFile()));
    email.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email , "Send Text File"));
```

Comment: Remove `Uri.parse("content://" + file.getAbsoluteFile())`. Use `FileProvider` and `getUriForFile()`.

Comment: Even if the file does not exist you continue creating an email intent. Well... do you think that is ok?